# Antd modal not showing on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to use **antd** for my react application but the provided modal doesn't seem to work. The button is visible, but nothing happens when I click it, no error is thrown.

I also tried this with other modals provided on their official [modal documentation](https://ant.design/components/modal/).

Modal code:

```
    import { Button, Modal } from 'antd';
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
    const App = () => {
      const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
    
      const showModal = () => {
        setIsModalOpen(true);
      };
    
      const handleOk = () => {
        setIsModalOpen(false);
      };
    
      const handleCancel = () => {
        setIsModalOpen(false);
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
            Open Modal
          </Button>
          <Modal title="Basic Modal" open={isModalOpen} onOk={handleOk} onCancel={handleCancel}>
            <p>Some contents...</p>
            <p>Some contents...</p>
            <p>Some contents...</p>
          </Modal>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Seems like Antd has updated the name of the property that is being passed to the Modal component.

The prop name `open` has changed to `visible`.

This code works:

```html
<Modal title="Basic Modal" visible={isModalOpen} onOk={handleOk} onCancel={handleCancel}>
    <p>Some contents...</p>
    <p>Some contents...</p>
    <p>Some contents...</p>
</Modal>
```

I found this by inspecting the element and altering the prop value.

Comment: FYI. There have been some changes on GitHub 14 days ago, see https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/36609, maybe they will change it back.

Comment: The prop name "visible" was for Antd 4.23 or lower. Make sure you change the version number for the documentation to the one you are using on the top bar on their website.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was the problem of the version. I am using 4.20.6. But as per the documentation they are using open prop, even for this 4.20.6.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import css correctly ?

```
import React, { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Everything was correct, like I said the prop open was changed to visible but its not mentioned in the documentation. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the CSS.

```css
import "antd/dist/antd.css"
```

This worked for me when I created a new app. But I faced the same issue when I tried to integrate `Modal` into a previous React application.

I tried changing `open` has changed to `visible`, but even that didn't let me know how you fixed it. I appreciate it.

Comment: Try updating the Ant version, this property might not work with older versions.